# Fetching array values into the IN clause of a SQL

Tags: java, sql

How can we use a Java array values in the IN clause of an SQL statement?

Example :

```
String[] names={"Abc","Bac","lol"};
String query= select * from Table1 where name in (using the Names array as a look up)
```

Comment: It doesn't depend on Java directly.  It depends on the library you're using to interact with your database.  What database are you using and what drivers/libraries are you using in Java?

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah  agree.I added it for the better semantical clarity of the Language I am using. I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: You still haven't said what java libraries you are using to connect to Oracle.  It's those libraries that facilitate this, or not...